# Windows command line script to search for file and then check permissions

Tags: windows, file, shell, command-line, batch-file

I have a command line script I'm testing to search an entire directory for a given file (e.g. cmd.exe).  This script is working well and returns the full path to each found file.

```
for /r C:\ %i in (*) do @echo %~fi | find /I "cmd.exe"
```

Now I would like to expand on this script and once a file is found check the permissions (e.g. icacls %~fi).  I would like to keep this to a one-liner on the command line, if possible.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %I in ('dir /b /s cmd.exe') do icacls "%I"
```

Is that what you were looking for?  If you don't want to have to cd to c:\ on a separate line then change it thusly:

```
pushd "\" && for /f "tokens=*" %I in ('dir /b /s cmd.exe') do (icacls "%I") && popd
```

There you go.  One-liner.  :)